# How to get PHP to read in the contents of "textfile.txt"?

Tags: php

Versions of this question have been asked before, but I am still none the wiser about how to make PHP read *any* content from a file and use it as a variable - whether the first line, a defined number of characters, or the whole thing - and then echo it back to an .html page. So I have tried to simplify this question right down.

I have the following three files at the paths shown (this is exactly how the paths look to my FTP program, except that I have made "my_username" and "my_domain" generic) and with the contents shown:

`my_username/my_domain/test.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html>  
<head>  
</head>
<body>
Yes!
<?php include ("../new-dir/testprogram.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`my_username/new-dir/testprogram.php`:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("testfile.txt")."No";
?>
```

`my_username/new-dir/testfile.txt`:

```
Hello, I am testfile.txt!
This is the second line in this file.
This is the third.
```

When I browse to `my_domain.com/test.php` I simply get a webpage saying

```
Yes! No
```

As you can see, the inline PHP on the client side is reading the PHP on `testprogram.php` on the server side, and the `echo` command in the latter code is being executed. The problem is that `echo` is only acting on what comes after the ".", namely the word "No". I have tried hard to debug this, and the above is the simplest showcase of the problem I have arrived at so far. I have just not been able to get PHP to demonstrate that it has processed anything at all from the file `testfile.txt`. It is as if the function `file_get_contents` is being ignored, even though I copied the contents of my file `testprogram.pgp` from the example usage of this function given on [its page in the PHP documentation at W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp). For debugging purposes I only made a single alteration, namely by tacking on "No" as a second argument of the `echo` function - and *that's* not the problem. I'd be very grateful for any help with this.

Comment: Try `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/testfile.txt")`. See [Magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php) Also, it's pretty odd to have PHP code in an `.html` file

Comment: See also [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: PHP's include path is often a point of confusion. The general advice is to use `__DIR__` to make sure you know exactly where your relative path begins

Comment: Many thanks, @Phil! That works fine. The page now reads, as it should, `Yes! Hello, I am testfile.txt! This is the second line in this file. This is the third.No`. Apologies - I meant to type "test.php" not "test.html". I'll correct.